# Stretch multiple DIVs to 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css

I want to center 3 DIVs placed in wrapper DIV. Point is that those DIVs will stretch out their WIDTH individually so they can together match the width of wrapper which is 100%.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content2</div>
    <div>Content3</div>
</div>
```

Anybody know how this is done? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you i will check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS table layout, browser support is great - **IE8+**.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t5hu8ybq/)**</kbd>

```css
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /* table-layout: fixed; */
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrapper > div {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content2</div>
    <div>Content3</div>
</div>
```

Note `.wrapper { table-layout: fixed; }` is for equal width cells.

Comment: Yeah this kinda work but i forgot to mention that i gonna use that in responsive design and display TABLE dont work when you resize your page..

Comment: What do you want to do when resize page, like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/341uf2rt/)?

Comment: Yes exactly that but for some reason it dont work in my code.

Comment: I think it's the typo problem that I corrected in the question - `wraper` vs `wrapper`, the 2nd one is a better english word, hehe :P

Comment: Ok thats the stuff i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: In the demo link of the previous comment, the media query part is missing a closing tag of `}` if you haven't noticed it, all fixed in the updated answer, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you went the `flexbox` approach, your CSS would probably be this simple:

```
.wraper{
    display:flex;
}
.wraper > div{
    width:100%;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/869vvx7L/1/) for a demo

Comment: Good idea, worth to mention - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and don't forget to add all the prefixes to make it to work on all major browers.

Comment: Yeah damn this also works but i forgot mention that im gonna use that for responsive deisgn and with that those DIV wont reposition themselfs when you resize your page.

Comment: @Mitre Thats easy.... just add a media query like in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/869vvx7L/2/), just change the `flex-direction`