# Align 3 section inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 section inside an div and div have a `max-width: 1024px;`. I make the first 1 float to left and the 3rd one float to right. But the 2nd one, I tried to set it in-between 1st and 3rd using `margin: 0 auto;`, it did not work...

[How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Here is my [Jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/dv6ttzbk/3/)

Something like `[LEFT]    [CENTER]    [RIGHT]`

Comment: This is a very old problem that people have found many solutions to. There are literally thousands upon thousands of show-cases and tutorials out there. You just have to open a search engine.

Comment: Can you change the order of the div's?

Comment: @Marc Audet I did try to change the order but it did not work..

Comment: it sounds very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31329610/483779) that I answered earlier.

Comment: or use display: flex http://jsfiddle.net/fq3rbzy2/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a possible solution using CSS [Calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

> The `calc()` CSS function can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`,
>   `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is required. With `calc()`, you
>   can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1024px;
  border:1px dotted green;
  font-size: 0; /*fix inline block gap*/
  /* margin: 0 auto; - if you want the #wrap to be centered uncomment this line*/
}
.yolo {
  width: 29.297%; /* 300px/1024px=0.29297 */
  /*max-width: 300px; - this line should be commented if you want to fill the parent with the childs .yolo */
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px /* show font due to font-size 0 in parent*/
}
.yolo:first-of-type {
  background: yellow
}
.yolo:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: gray;
  width: calc(100% - 58.594%) /* width x 2 (29.297% x2) */
}
.yolo:last-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <section class="yolo molo1">Hello</section>
  <section class="yolo molo3">Hey</section>
  <section class="yolo molo2">Hi</section>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** OP's Comments below

**1st:**

> Thanks, but i wanted to be 3 individual like there is a gap between
>   them

**2nd:**

> Btw, Does calc() function in css work in every other browser?

### Answer:

**Snippet** *with gap between them*

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  border:1px dotted green;
  font-size: 0; /*fix inline block gap*/
  /* margin: 0 auto; - if you want the #wrap to be centered uncomment this line*/
}
.yolo {
  width: 29.297%; /* 300px/1024px=0.29297 */
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-right:6%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px /* show font due to font-size 0 in parent*/
}
.yolo:first-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}
.yolo:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: gray;
  width: calc(100% - 70.594%) /* width: (29.297% x 2)+(6% x 2) */
}
.yolo:last-of-type {
  background: blue;
  margin-right:0
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <section class="yolo molo1">Hello</section>
  <section class="yolo molo3">Hey</section>
  <section class="yolo molo2">Hi</section>
</div>
```

#### CSS Calc() function works from [IE9 and above](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted to be 3 individual like there is a gap between them.

Comment: that's easy, how much gap you want between them?

Comment: Btw, Does `calc()` function in css work in every other browser?

Comment: For the gap, i wanted the 3rd one to float to the right and 2nd one right in the middle of both of them.

Comment: Something like `[LEFT]       [CENTER]       [RIGHT]`

Comment: i just updated the answer , by answering all your questions/comments. please take a look

Comment: If you look at this answer in full page mode, the blue div does not go to the right edge of the parent wrapper div.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the order of your `div` elements, you can get the result that you want as follows.

Float `.molo1` to the left and `.molo2` to the right.

Keep `.molo3` as non-floated content and set the left/right margins to 35%, which is 70% divided by 2, 70% being the width left over after taking into account the width of the central div.

If needed, set `margin: 0 auto` to the wrapping element if you need to center it (optional).

```css
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    margin: 0 auto; /* if you want centering */
}
section.yolo {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
section.molo1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}
section.molo2 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
section.molo3 {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 35%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <section class="yolo molo1">Hello</section>
    <section class="yolo molo2">Hi</section>
    <section class="yolo molo3">Hey</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `width:33%;` for each and get rid of the `float:right`.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/29zatakh/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with Flex Box:[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ew5rgsd8/)

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    display:flex;
}
.molo1, .yolo {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background: yellow;
    justify-content:space-between;
      margin:2em;
    padding:1em;

}
.molo3 {
    background: gray;

}
.molo2 {

    background: blue;
}
```